# How to solve a linear interpolation data by time step in R : (list) object can not be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r, database, coercion, linear-interpolation

I have data of instantaneous water discharge under a file data.txt (data below)

> (list) object can not be coerced to type 'double'
>    
>   I think the problem is due to the format of the dates, please how to solve this problem?

```
write.table(TAB4, file="Q.txt", sep=";",quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two changes needed.  The `list` problem can be solved by converting x to `POSIXct`, not `POSIXlt` in section 6 of your code: `x=as.POSIXct(TAB3$V1)`.

Then, in section 7, remove the `NA` values from x and y: `TAB4=approx(x[-z],y[-z], xout= x[z])`.

There is also a spurious p in `pTAB4` in the following line that looks wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew Gustar. The program works now